# swiftUI : Updating Text after changes in settings

Tags: swiftui

[Edit(1) to reflect [posting of streamlined app](https://github.com/Esowes/refreshFromModal) to illustrate the issue : ].
[Edit (2) : completely removed EnvironmentObject and app now works ! Not understanding WHY body is refreshed as NO @State vars are being modified...Code at end of text]

I am writing an app that, at some point, displays some text, related to the contents of 2 Arrays, depending on a set of rules. These rules can be set in a Settings view, as User's preference.
So, when a user changes the rules he wants applied in Settings, that text needs to be re-assessed.
But of course, things aren't that easy.
I present my settings view as modal on my main ContentView, and when I dismiss that modal, the body of the ContentView is not redrawn...

I created an EnvironmentObject with @Published vars in order to keep track of all the user preferences (that are also written to UserDefaults), and shared that @EnvironmentObject with both my ContentView and SettingsView, in the hope that, being an observedObject, its changes would trigger a refresh of my ContentView.

Not so...

Any ideas to help me go forward on this ? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated (again!).

[Posted app on GitHub](https://github.com/Esowes/refreshFromModal) has following architecture :

An `appState` EnvironmentObject,
A `ContentView` that displays a set of texts, depending on some user preferences set in 
A `settingsView`

UserDefaults are initialized in `AppDelegate`.

Thanks for any help on this...

Content view :

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

  @State var modalIsPresented = false // The "settingsView" modally presented as a sheet

  @State private var modalViewCaller = 0 // This triggers the appropriate modal (only one in this example)

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                    VStack {
                    Text(generateStrings().text1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
                    Text(generateStrings().text2)
                    } // end of VStack
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .lineLimit(nil) // allows unlimited lines
                        .padding(.all)
                Spacer()
            } // END of main VStack
            .onAppear() {
                self.modalViewCaller = 0
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Test app", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: (
                Button(action: {
                    self.modalViewCaller = 6 // SettingsView
                    self.modalIsPresented = true
                }
                    ) {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                     }
            ))
        } // END of NavigationView
        .sheet(isPresented: $modalIsPresented, content: sheetContent)
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) // This avoids dual column on iPad

    } // END of var body: some View

  // MARK: @ViewBuilder func sheetContent() :

    @ViewBuilder func sheetContent() -> some View {

        if modalViewCaller == 6 {
            SettingsView()
            }
    } // END of func sheetContent


    // MARK: generateStrings() : -

    func generateStrings() -> (text1: String, text2: String, recapText: String, isHappy: Bool) { // minimumNumberOfEventsCheck

        var myBool = false
        var aString = "" // The text 1 string
        var bString = "" // The text 2 string
        var cString = "" // The recap string

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: kmultiRules) { // The user chose the dual rules option
            let ruleSet = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: kruleSelection) + 1
            aString = "User chose 2 rules option"
            bString = "User chose rule set # \(ruleSet)"
            myBool = true
            print("isDualRules true loop : generateStrings was called at \(Date().debugDescription)")
            cString = "Dual rules option, user chose rule set nb \(ruleSet)"
        }
            else // The user chose the single rule option
        {
            aString = "User chose single rule option"
            bString = "User had no choice : there is only one set of rules !"
            myBool = false
            print("isDualRules false loop : generateStrings was called at \(Date().debugDescription)")
            cString = "Single rule option, user chose nothing."
        }


            return (aString, bString, cString, myBool)
    } // End of func generatestrings() -> String

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        return ContentView()

    }
}
```

SettingsView :

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct SettingsView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode // in order to dismiss the Sheet

    @State public var multiRules = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: kmultiRules)

    @State private var ruleSelection = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: kruleSelection) // 0 is rule 1, 1 is rule 2


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {

                Toggle(isOn: $multiRules)
                {
                    Text("more than one rule ?")
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)

                if multiRules {
                            Picker("", selection: $ruleSelection){
                                Text("rules 1").tag(0)
                                Text("rules 2").tag(1)
                            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        }

            } // End of List
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                Button("Done") {
                        self.saveDefaults() // We try to save once more if needed
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // This dismisses the view
                }
            )
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
        } // END of Navigation view
    } // END of some View


    func saveDefaults() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(multiRules, forKey: kmultiRules)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(ruleSelection, forKey: kruleSelection)
    }    
}



// MARK: Preview struct

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        return SettingsView()
    }
}
```

Constants.swift file :

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

let kmultiRules = "two rules"
let kruleSelection = "rules selection"
let kappStateChanged = "appStateChanged"
```

AppDelegate :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [ // We initialize the UserDefaults
        "two rules": false,
        "rules selection": 0, // 0 is ruel 1, 1 is rule 2
        "appStateChanged": false
        ])

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Let's start from demo code of problem...

Comment: read and cosider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This is not a "we writee code for you for free" platform, but a "we help you with your code you got so far"-platform.

Comment: Well, I never considered this platform to be anything like a "code for free" venue. I have always provided clear code to illustrate any of my problems. I was just looking for a pointer here... The code of my app is now so long, it is hard for me to extract a working skeleton in order to provide code. Will be investigating Notification Center tomorrow, it seems promising for my issue.

Comment: Tried the Notification Center approach by triggering it in the onDissappear as Olaf suggested, no joy... I streamlined the app to the maximum and posted it on GitHub if anyone has some time to spend on this... Thanks. https://github.com/Esowes/refreshFromModal

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared @EnvironmentObject with @Published properties in two views, if you change such a property from one view, the other one will be re-execute the body property and the view will be updated.

It really helps to create simple standalone examples - not only for asking here, also for gaining a deeper understanding / getting an idea why it doesn't work in the complex case.

For example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class TextSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count: Int = 1
}

struct TextSettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: TextSettings

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker(selection: $settings.count, label:
                Text("Text Repeat Count"))
            {
                ForEach(Array(1...5), id: \.self) { value in
                    Text(String(value)).tag(value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TextWithSettingExampleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: TextSettings

    var body: some View {
        Text(String(repeating: "Hello ", count: Int(settings.count)))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink("Settings", destination: TextSettingsView()))
    }

}

struct TextWithSettingExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TextWithSettingExampleView()
        }
        .environmentObject(TextSettings())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight Ralf, I updated my question : I built an example project ( https://github.com/Esowes/refreshFromModal ) but still can't get this to work. I am changing an Environment object's @Published properties, no success...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but I had what I believe might be a similar problem where I never got my contentview to reflect the updates in my observed object when the changes were triggered from a modal. I solved/hacked this by triggering an action in my observed object when dismissing the modal like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
//
@State var isPresentingModal = false
var body: some View {
//
.sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresentingModal) {
                        PresentedModalView()
                            .onDisappear {
                                //Do something here
                         }
                       }
                     }
                   }
```

Comment: Great idea as this onDisappear is always triggered, contrary to onAppear. But texts still won't update ! I edited my question with a link to an example App I created by streamlining my existing app as much as I could : https://github.com/Esowes/refreshFromModal

Comment: Glanced at your project, have you tried calling "self.appState.updateValues()"  from onDisappear in your content view? Just a wild guess.

Comment: Yes, I did, no joy... I completely deconstructed my app and for rid of the Environment Object, changed the if arguments in my generateStrings func to the direct UserDefaults values and now, the body of my ContentView is refreshed, even though no @State variables are modified ! In short, the app works, but I don't know why... Will EDIT the question with my code...